# #Error in SSRS tablix but ok in SQL side of SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using Visual studio 2019 with SDDT 2017.
My report pulls the data direct from SAP B1, all of the fields in the SQL query designer give the output I am expecting. When I use this data in building my tablix I get a #Error.

The calculation that works ok in SQL is WOR1.IssuedQty - OWOR.CmpltQty * WOR1.BaseQty, the answer gives me 11 decimal places

I have narrowed it down to the field WOR1.BaseQty this field is causing the output to Error., the field in SQl shows the type as numeric ( 19,6) ( as it does for the other numeric fields in the table but they all present ok in the ssrs output tablix and as I say calculates all ok.
When I choose the field in the Tablix I get no answer just #Error. I have tried casting and converting the output of the calculation in SQL side and within adding a filed post SQL ( in the dataset properties and within the Tablix,to different data types but still get the error.

I have exhausted google.

I would appreciate some help ….. please....

Thanks

Tony

Comment: I also get an error 'calculatedFieldWrapperlmpl' to type 'integer' is not valid

Comment: Is the error happening just showing the field in your report or performing any sort of calculation on it?

Comment: No the calculation is ok in the SQL side of Visual studio in the query designer view I get the answer, when I am in the report I just get the error

Comment: Do you have any formatting on the cell where the value is displayed? if not.. what happens if you wrap it with a format of some sort? Something like = format(fields!yourfield.value,"0.0000000000000;(0.0000000000000)")

Comment: Tried all of that and still did not resolve it, I have got around it, but I would like to understand the correct way to resolve it as I have other issues on a similar theme with what I think is the data type.